# Is there any way to insert data to couch base lite without using External library?

Tags: android, couchbase

I am using **Couchbase Lite** instead of **SQLite** in my android application. In the documentation of couch base lite they have said to refer **Grocery_sync application**.

In Grocery sync app they have used **extrop external library** to insert,update and delete the document in the data base.

My question was "Is there any way to perform this insert,update and delete operation directly with out using that library in couchBaseLite"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use another library, as mentioned in the documentation

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-android/#developing-apps

> We’re currently working on native APIs for Android. In the meantime, there’s a number of tools in the wild that you can use in conjunction with our REST APIs. Some of the examples in this section use one such tool, Ektorp.

An alternative that you could use would be: http://www.lightcouch.org/